# Is There Any Work Around In Exporting Msaccess Query Table With Calculated Field Using Excel Vba Ado?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

Hi I have a Calculated Query Table name DataQuery like

Date / RJournal / AMount

where Rjournal is a calculated field

Rjournal : DLookUp("REFjournal","DV","ChckID > 0 and Payee = '" & [Payee] & "' and Dvnumber = " & [Dvnumber] & "")

And it works fine.

But since MS Access is my Database and Excel is my front end and most of my users are excel users. I created an Export Button to export this Query to excel using ADO in excel. For some reason the Field RJournal wont capture its data it just leave blank

But if I use access Menu External Data then Export to Excel all data will be present.

I wonder if ADO supports Exporting Calculated Table query.

```
Private Sub Export_Click()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath As String
Dim SQL As String

'add error handling
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'Disable screen flickering.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'clear the values from the worksheet
Sheets("Data").Range("A2:C500000").ClearContents

'get the path to the database
dbPath = Sheets("Update Version").Range("b1").Value

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection ' Initialise the collection class variable

'Connection class is equipped with a —method— named Open
'—-4 aguments—- ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
'ConnectionString formula—-Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key_n=Value_n;
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

SQL = "SELECT * FROM DATAQUERY"

'Create the ADODB recordset object.

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

'ConnectionString Open '—-5 aguments—-
'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options
rs.Open SQL, cnn

'Check if the recordset is empty.
If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
'Close the recordet and the connection.
rs.Close
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
'Enable the screen.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'In case of an empty recordset display an error.
MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"

Exit Sub
End If


'Write the reocrdset values in the sheet.
Sheets("DATA").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

'Close the recordset and the connection.
rs.Close
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

'Enable the screen.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True



'Inform the user that the macro was executed successfully.
MsgBox "Congratulation the data has been successfully Imported", vbInformation, "Import successful"
'error handler
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:
'clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Import_Data"

END SUB
```

I EXPECT AN OUTCOUME LIKE THIS

Date / RJournal / AMount
01 /CRJ / 1000
02 /CDJ / 1000
03  /CRJ /1000
04  /CRJ /1500

BUT ENDS UP LIKE THIS

Date / RJournal / AMount
01 / / 1000
02 / / 1000
03 / /1000
04 / /1500

Comment: Testing with ADODB and DAO does not indicate any problems with exporting a calculated field.  In addition I'm having trouble understanding the expected output and the actual output. You gave an example of `RJournal` but in your example for expected output, this field doesn't have an issue. Please snapshot or table format your current result, desired result and what I'm guessing are calculated fields `CRJ`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Inner Select Query In MSAccess Queries Will do the work.

I made 3 table Queries

Table 1 Compose of
Date
DVnumber
Payee
Amount

Table2 Compose of
RefJournal
DVnumber
Payee

So in Table 3
Date
RJournal: (Select REFjournal From Table2 where Table1.DvNumber = Table2.DVnumber and Table1.Payee=Table2.Payee)
Amount

Or Under SQL

```
   SELECT Table1.Date, (Select REFjournal From Table2 where Table1.DvNumber = 
   Table2.DVnumber and Table1.Payee=Table2.Payee) as Rjournal, Table1.AMOUNT
   FROM Table1;
```

The Only Downside it is very Slow if exported to Excel Using Excel ADO VBA.